# How to inherit properties from only one of the types in a union of interfaces

Tags: typescript, interface, union

How do I make the Object `x` have properties from only one of `A`, `B`, `C`. Currently, it can have all the properties `a`, `b`, `c`, I only want it to be one of these and none of the other.

```js
interface A {
  a: string;
}
interface B {
  b: string;
}
interface C {
  c: string;
}

type X = A | B | C;

const x: X = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: 'c'
};

console.log(x); // returns { a: "a", b: "b", c: "c" }, should throw error.
```

Typescript version - 3.8.3

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the TypeScript documentation ([here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions)) I'm not sure this is possible using interfaces (I may well be wrong). But I did manage to achieve something like what you're looking for using Enums.

```
enum A {
  a = 'a'
}
enum B {
  b = 'b'
}
enum C {
  c = 'c'
}

type X = A | B | C;

const x: X = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: 'c'
};
/* This does throw an error:
Type '{ a: string; b: string; c: string; }' is not assignable to type 'X'.
  Type '{ a: string; b: string; c: string; }' is not assignable to type 'C'.
```

Comment: But enum only supports `string` and `number` I need this to be an interface because the properties will be nested objects. i used string only as an example.